# How to add function outputs to listbox/combobox as an item in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file search function. User can enter a keyword about what they look like and my function returns files in specific directory. I'm really newbie for control elements. My problem is how to add the results in ActiveX Listbox and Combobox as an item.

For example my function founds 3 results and i want to list them like;

- File1
- File2
- File3

when user select the File 1 and then click to go button they will get the path.

But as is said i cannot be able to add it with `.AddItem`  to Combo/List box .

How is it possible to implement that?

Comment: What is preventing you from using `.AddItem`? Please show what you have tried. As much as possible, please give a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman yea it seems a bit messy i mean i can add by 'Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.AddItem "File1"' 'but is there any easy way to put it ?

Comment: If you want to use `.AddItem` then you need to establish a VBA reference to the list boc object. You could assign `Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object` to a variable so that you don't always have to type it. You could also experiment with having storing the values in a sheet somewhere and having the `ListRange` property point to that range.